# Fix Version String Error in FreeNX Setup

Tags: opensuse, nx

On OpenSUSE 12.1, I would like to install and run the FreeNX Server. OpenSUSE [has provided instructions](http://en.opensuse.org/SDB%3aFreeNX_server) about the installation for previous versions, and I can adapt them for 12.1, up to a point.

I have taken these steps:

```
zypper ar http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/X11:/RemoteDesktop/openSUSE_12.1 RemoteDesktop
zypper ref
zypper in FreeNX
mkdir /usr/lib64/cups/backend/ipp
nxsetup --install --setup-nomachine-key
```

I didn't hit many of the issues that the OpenSUSE instructions page listed, so I didn't have to take those steps.

However, at the `nxsetup` step, after a few normal warnings (about not being able to use a printer and things like that), the setup script gives me an error:

> Error: Could not find 1.5.0 or 2.[01].0 or 3.[0123].0 version string
>   in nxagent. NX 1.5.0 or 2.[01].0 or 3.[0123].0 backend is needed for
>   this version of FreeNX.

How do I address this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution took two steps. I found that the **nxsetup** script calls the **nxloadconfig** (`/usr/bin/nxloadconfig`) script, and it was failing because of a condition on line 675:

```
[ -z "$(strings $COMMAND_NXAGENT | egrep 'NXAGENT - Version 1.5.0|NXAGENT - Version 2.[01].0|NXAGENT - Version 3.[0123].0')" ] && \
    WARNING="yes" && echo "Error: Could not find 1.5.0 or 2.[01].0 or 3.[0123].0 version string in nxagent. NX 1.5.0 or 2.[01].0 or 3.[0123].0 backend is needed for this version of FreeNX."
```

First, the target string in my `nxagent` application had the text `NXAGENT - Version 3.4.0`, so the script reported correctly, it could not find a version string in the range it wanted. So, [from another forum](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=280381), I updated the script to include versions 3.4.0 and 3.5.0 in the search (updated the grep expression to include `[012345]` instead of just `[0123]`).

But, even though I did this, **nxsetup** still gave me the same error. I then began investigating the **strings** command that the script used and eventually found that I didn't have **strings** on my system. The **binutils** package provides the **strings** command, and I had to install it from the OSS repository.

```
zypper in binutils
```

It looks like the FreeNX package missed a dependency or just assumed that any system should have **strings** on it, which I discovered is not the case.